# How do I limit number of records in table, so that old records are deleted, but new rows are kept?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I have a table in our oracle database that is tracking downloads based on the users session in a web application.  Over the past few years, this table has grown to millions of records, which is slowing down the application.

I would like to limit this table to only keep the items from the past week, and have it automatically remove the older records.  The table has a date field called DOWNLOAD_DATE which could be used for this query.

Is this something I can do with triggers?  If so, what is the best way to do so?

Comment: You can probably solve the performance problem with indexes or table partitioning.

Comment: Its true, but partitioning is available only in Enterprise Edition and only as paid option.

Comment: Well, you're clearly using this in a business context. I suggest that you pay for the features you need. And the answer is "partitioning".

Comment: Have a look at [`dbms_scheduler`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sched.htm). Have a job run every day/hour/whatever to delete rows/drop partitions.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that a trigger is the right thing for that, as it is executed on every insert/update/delete. I would recommend to create a procedure for that which performs a statement like "delete from table_name where trunc(download_date) < trunc(sysdate - 7);"

Then you schedule that procedure to be executed every hour or day based on your needs.

After the delete you may want to refresh the table stats with "DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS ('schema_name', 'table_name');"

More regarding gathering stats can be found here: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_dbms_stats_gather_table_stats.htm

Answer (score 0):

> Is this something I can do with triggers? If so, what is the best way
>   to do so?

Well i would say, a `Statement level` trigger is well suited for this problem. Read about statement level trigger [Here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/database-triggers-overview)

See demo:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE tab2 (
    col          VARCHAR(1),
    start_date   DATE,
    end_date     DATE
   );
  /
 Table created

SQL> Select * from tab2;
COL START_DATE  END_DATE
--- ----------- -----------
A   11-07-2019  18-07-2019
A   11-07-2019  31-07-2019
A   06-07-2019  31-07-2019
A   01-07-2019  31-07-2019  --- See this row is 10 days older than Sysdate

-- Created Statement level trigger 
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER t1
  2  BEFORE  INSERT ON tab2
  3  BEGIN
  4      DELETE FROM tab2
  5      WHERE start_date <= SYSDATE - 7; -- Deleting records older that 7 days from sysdate
  6  END;
  7  /
Trigger created

SQL> Insert into tab2 values('A',sysdate+1,sysdate+10);
1 row inserted

SQL> commit;
Commit complete

-- You can see the records older that 7 days from sysdate is deleted
SQL> Select * from tab2;
COL START_DATE  END_DATE
--- ----------- -----------
A   11-07-2019  18-07-2019
A   11-07-2019  31-07-2019
A   06-07-2019  31-07-2019
A   12-07-2019  21-07-2019
```

Answer (score 0):

IF I had requirement like this, I would go like this:

PROCEDURE p1
IS
BEGIN
   LOOP
      DELETE FROM table123               --- you can give your table name here
            WHERE download_date <= SYSDATE - 7 AND ROWNUM <= 10000; ---if you want to restrict to delete the rows at a time

```
  EXIT WHEN SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0;

  COMMIT;

  DBMS_LOCK.sleep (10); ----- if you want to give sleep time as per your requirement
```

END LOOP;
END;

this job will run for 24*7 and delete all the records which are older  than 7 days